# Websphere throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for Spring service impl class

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I am having a problem with spring service class. I have created a serviceImpl class that implements a service interface. When i run this in my local Websphere instance it run fine. But when i run it in a different websphere environment i get a no such method error.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public interface WorkflowResolverService {

    Integer getCurrentlyManagedClientProfileIntId();

    List getAvailableStatusGroup(String moduleName);

    List getAvailableFunctionsByGroup(String moduleName, Short statusId);

    List getAvailableFunctionsById(String moduleName, Short status);
```

}

```
@Service
public class WorkflowResolverServiceImpl implements WorkflowResolverService {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WorkflowResolverServiceImpl.class);

//private static WorkflowResolver workFlowResolver;

    /*@Autowired
    public WorkflowResolverServiceImpl(WorkflowResolver workFlowResolver){
        WorkflowResolverServiceImpl.workFlowResolver = workFlowResolver;
    }*/

    @Override
    public Integer getCurrentlyManagedClientProfileIntId() {
        log.debug("Entered WorkflowResolverServiceImpl     getCurrentlyManagedClientProfileIntId");
        return 0;

}

@Override
    public List getAvailableStatusGroup(String moduleName) {
        log.debug("Entered WorkflowResolverServiceImpl     getAvailableStatusGroup");
        return new ArrayList();
        //return workFlowResolver.getAvailableStatusGroup2(moduleName);
    }

    @Override
    public List getAvailableFunctionsByGroup(String moduleName, Short statusId) {
        log.debug("Entered WorkflowResolverServiceImpl getAvailableFunctionsByGroup");
        return new ArrayList();
        //return workFlowResolver.getAvailableFunctionsByGroup2(moduleName, statusId);
    }

    @Override
    public List getAvailableFunctionsById(String moduleName, Short status) {
        log.debug("Entered WorkflowResolverServiceImpl getAvailableFunctionsById");
        return new ArrayList();
        //return workFlowResolver.getAvailableFunctionsById2(moduleName,     status);
    }
```

}

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/template/searchGlobalTemplate.htm"})
public class GlobalTemplateListController
  extends BaseFormController2
{
  private static final Log log =   LogFactory.getLog(GlobalTemplateListController.class);
  @Autowired
  private TemplateService templateService;
  @Autowired
  private WorkflowResolverService workflowResolverService;

  private static final String TEMPLATE_SEARCH_VIEW = "globalTemplateList";

  @RequestMapping(method=  {org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET})
  public String init(ModelMap map)
  {
   log.debug("Initializing Search Global Template Form");

    TemplateSearchCmd cmd = new TemplateSearchCmd();

    List<StatusGroup> statusList =     this.workflowResolverService.getAvailableStatusGroup(this.moduleName);
cmd.setStatus(statusList);

    map.put("command", cmd);

    return "globalTemplateList";
  }
```

When i try to access any of these service calls in my controller i get the following error in websphere

> Blockquote
>   [12/15/16 4:41:53:026 EST] 000000b4 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet springmvc in application Entitlement. Exception created : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.citi.cds.entl.service.WorkflowResolverService.getAvailableStatusGroup(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
>   Blockquote

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't mention how are you calling service class? Also it's not a best practice to annotate interface with `@Transactional`

Comment: Sorry the service class is being called in a spring controller. I have included it in the original question

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: com.citi.cds.entl.service.WorkflowResolverService.getAvailableStatusGroup` - looks like this class is in different version on your other environment. Maybe its in a shared library not updated? Try to reinstall app and restart the server, if it is included in the app itself.

Comment: I have retrieve the jar file that contains the classes described from the websphere deployment directory and decompiled them and the methods are correct in the decompiled class

Comment: Another question, which Java are you using? It sounds stupid, but I know that IBM has standard IBM Java used instead of Oracle Java. Maybe you're running into a problem here, as Spring is compiled against Oracle Java and both Java RE's are not exactly the same. I ran into simular problems when using WebSphere... though I don't know anything about a WorkflowResolverService class...

Comment: I'd agree with Gas' suggestion - is there perhaps more than one copy of that class floating around somewhere?  It's possible that it's packaged in more than one jar in the application (in which case the load order is indeterminate), or in some other location like the Java classpath that gets picked up in preference to the copy in the app.

Comment: Running on Java 1.6. No i have checked and there is only one version on the class floating around. I have also grabbed the ear file that is running in  sit environment and deployed it on my local websphere and it runs fine

Comment: You need other tools for this kind of problem. @see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972177

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved. Out of desperation i changed the interface name by adding a 1 to the end, regenerated the ear and redeployed. The error is gone and application is running okay now. Go figure. Thanks for all the suggestions.